# Confused about nginx mainline / development version

Tags: nginx, server

I've been following tutorials of installing nginx mainline on Ubuntu, but I keep getting nginx version 1.10 no matter what.

On the nginx website, it says the [latest mainline version](http://nginx.org/en/download.html) is 1.9.15. However, on [LaunchPad](https://launchpad.net/~nginx/+archive/ubuntu/development) (where I use deb-src to install nginx), it says that the latest mainline version on the bottom is 1.10. Which is actually the latest version for the mainline?

Comment: Next mainline should be 1.11, but they didn't release that yet. So they give you latest available version.

Comment: See https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-1-10-1-11-released/